# Why does only the last function display on the console?

Tags: javascript

Just curious as to why its not printing both peter.attack() and kegann.attack() in the console.

console for this function:

"attacks with fire"

```
function createElf(name, weapon) {
    return {

        name,
        weapon,
        attack(){
            return 'attack with ' + weapon

        }
    }
}

const peter = createElf('Peter', 'stones')
peter.attack();

const kegann = createElf('Sam', 'fire')
kegann.attack();
```

Comment: Because when you run a script in the console, it always only prints the result of the last statement. If you want to print other/more things, use `console.log`. (If it would implicitly log the result of every function call, it would be quite a mess)

Comment: @Bergi Oh wow. I had no idea lol. Thank you.